# Split messages and route them in camel

Tags: java, integration, apache-camel

I have a large XML message read from queue, I need to split it in chunks and convert it into objects and then route them to various destinations based on the object.

So I have configured the routeBuilder to

```
ChoiceDefinition choice = from(routeConfig.getFromEndpoint())
                .split().method(xmlSplitter, "splitMessage").streaming().process(xmlProcessor).choice();
for (RouteConfig filter : filters) {
    choice = choice.when(header(REPORT_TYPE_HEADER_NAME).contains(filter.getReportTypeHeaderFilter()))
                    .to(filter.getToEndpoint());
}
choice.otherwise().to(routeConfig.getErrorEndpoint());
```

But the routing is not happening at all, All messages are sent to the errorEndpoint. 
I found the reason to be the splitter deleting the header, as its ahead of the routing.

It seems I cannot use splitting after routing.

What is the solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split() shouldn't remove the headers...are you sure your xmlSplitter/xmlProcessor aren't causing issues?

here is a simple example to show that the headers are preserved...

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:mock")
protected MockEndpoint mock;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    mock.expectedMessageCount(2);
    mock.expectedHeaderReceived("foo","bar");
    template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:start", "msg1,msg2", "foo", "bar");
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

            from("direct:start")
                .to("log:+++before+++?showHeaders=true")
                .split().method(MySplitterBean.class, "splitBody").streaming()
                .to("log:+++after+++?showHeaders=true")
                .choice().when(header("foo").contains("bar"))
                    .to("mock:mock")
                .otherwise()
                    .to("mock:error");
        }
    };
}

public static class MySplitterBean {
    public List<String> splitBody(String body) {
        List<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] parts = body.split(",");
        for (String part : parts) {
            answer.add(part);
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```